# How to pass a function value into a text box on click event. Function value is also an output of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, css

```
I have posted code on following path of [JsFiddle][1]: =cqo2fk75=
```

I have put my used code there.
Please suggest.

Comment: Path isnt accesible..Why are u putting it in an array??

Comment: I have update my quest with fiddle path, see value between "="

Comment: I have used array because I want to choose multiple values. Could you please suggest an other code for same.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes in your code. For example

1. Copied `jquery` in CSS input of fiddle.
2. `<input type="button" id="startBtn" name="b" value="Get Value" />
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
3. Returning value in an event handler (won't help)

I have updated your fiddle. Have a look
http://jsfiddle.net/cqo2fk75/2/